# when i select row in gridview i get another result

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview in my asp.net webform, and if i select row

- after the database is refreshed  i see the ID correct.

but when i run any query on the data and i see for example 4 rows

and i select one row i see wrong ID

i use this for select row:  `ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;`

what can be wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Need more information.  Some sample data, a screenshot of the grid, the desired behavior, the actual behavior.

Comment: At which point are you trying to pull the ID or what event do you use? SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedIndexChanging?

Comment: Where and when are you binding the gridview to its Datasource? And are you doing it on every postback or only if `!IsPostBack`?

Comment: What *could* be wrong is that you're querying for an absolute position that isn't the *first* position.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ID row the first column in your gridview? If yes, try using SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text.

You may also want to take a look at this link:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article442-how-to-get-the-values-of-selected-row-from-a-gridview-using-aspnet-.aspx

Hope it helps!